# "Django-Gevent" or "Django-Nodejs-redis"?

Tags: django, node.js, socket.io

We have a [website](http://www.goftare.com) writen in django with 50,000 user on mobile and website.
We want to implement a realtime chat system.
We have searched and are considering two options:

1. Using Gevent-socketio in django: https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio
2. Using Django, Nodejs and redis: I found this project in github: https://github.com/data-tsunami/NodeJS-SocketIO-Redis-Python-Nginx

I have no experience on this, which one would you prefer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all my love to both Node.js and Python, I will do my best to not compare what is better, but instead be generic answering your question.

---

Cons of going Django + Node.js:

- Overhead in maintenance (two servers to worry about now)
- Expertise needed in two languages
- Extra code required to bridge the two servers: authentication, data access implementations, etc.

Pros of going Django + Node.js:

- Using best tools available to solve problems, instead of picking one and adapting it to everything.
- Wider professional experience (if it is relevant for you)

---

Summing it up, I do not think it is worth going extra language, unless existing one is utterly awful in what you want to achieve.

On the other hand, if the functionality you want to implement using different language is OK to be fully isolated, the overhead will be significantly lower, thus more attractive as a choice.

Comment: @alanderav:great. thanks. i think it's couldn't being esolated. we don't afraid of expertise, we worry about speed and performance of this solution.i want to know your idea.

Comment: Python is not slow language at all. Though if code is written bad, any language will execute it slow.

Comment: i agree. i mean the second solution isn't slower than the first?

Comment: Is Django + Node.js slower vs Django? No, unless in Django + Node.js you have to move a lot of data from one server to another.